# PERL SFTP using System, Cannot install SFTP module

Tags: perl, sftp

I'm a bit new to perl and stackoverflow. If I could use a more familiar language I would, unfortunately I cannot due to certain circumstances. Thanks in advance for the help.

Modules Not Installed: Net::SFTP, WWW::CURL, Net::SSH2, Net::SFTP::Foriegn
Modules Installed: Net::FTP

I am unable to install modules.

Unable to use Net::FTP Tried Default port and port 22, with a username and password. All I get back from the other box's log when trying to connect is "Did not receive identification string from xx.xx.xx.xx" Also unable to use FTP in command line, times out.

`$ftp = Net::FTP->new($box,Port=>22, Debug => 0)

   or die print "Error: Cannot connect";

$ftp->login($userBox,$passBox)

   or die print "Error: Cannot login";

$ftp->cwd()

   or die print "Error: Cannot change to Root";

$ftp->cwd($dir)

   or die print "Error: Cannot change to selected directory";

if($copyfile ne "" && $dir ne "")

   {

      $ftp->put($copyfile, $copyfile);

   }

$ftp->quit();`

I can manually use SFTP through the linux command line, not FTP, so I have been trying to use the system command to SFTP into the other box. The other box's logs just say "Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx"

`system('sftp '.$userBox.'@'.$box.' ENDOFINPUT'

.$passBox.'ENDOFINPUT

cd ../../../

put '.$filename.' '.$dir.'

exit

ENDOFINPUT');`

If anyone knows how to help me with my problem that'd be great :)

Comment: SFTP and FTP are two completely different protocols. There is no way to access an SFTP server using Net::SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

Let's approach this from another direction... when you say you're "unable to install modules", is that just because you don't have root permission? If that's the case, you can [install them locally under a user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735836/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-without-root-privileges) instead.

If the machine doesn't have an internet connection to even install them locally, you can use the same technique to install them on a different box, then gzip the entire local directory where you have them installed and copy them to the target machine, and add a "[use lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)" statement to get at them from your script.

Comment: Hmmm I did not know that I could do such a thing. I'd have to ask a senior to be sure I would be allowed to do something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the $passBox equivalent worked on the shell?

You should be able to set-up passwordless connectivity using key-pairs, which would make THAT problem go away quite quickly.

Comment: I have yes replaced the variables putting my credentials directly in the code to see if it was a variable issue or not. And the same credentials were used to SFTP in shell(assuming linux command line) I'm rather noob to linux boxes/perl. So lingo is not the best.

Comment: Let's be specific: what you did in the shell was exactly the same as the here document in perl, and it worked?  I'd be rather surprised if it did, quite frankly.  I didn't ask whether the credentials are correct, but whether the same syntax worked.

Comment: looking at the code, I accidentally deleted a bit @.@ let me quick fix that but what I put into linux command line. But the only bits that were not the same as the command line the Endofline stuff. sftp USER@BOX USER@BOX pass: input pass connected

Comment: So you entered the password interactively?

Comment: Command line Yes, sorry not able to format, atleast don't know how. So After I typed in the SFTP USER@BOX I was then prompted for a password once I put that password in I was allowed access.

Comment: OK ... short of using expect you WON'T be able to do what you want unless to switch to passwordless authentication.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into key-pairs now.