# How to use downloaded Net::SSH2 module in Perl?

Tags: perl, libssh2, perlnetssh

I have downloaded `Net-SSH2-0.43` to be able to use `Net::SSH2` Perl module. But I don't know what I need to do after that, just include paths or something else. Please help.

Comment: I tried, but I need root password. Also we have several machines and I will have to install it on all hosts

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735836/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-without-root-privileges

Comment: what OS/distribution?

Answer (score 2):

you could use perlbrew to install Perl in your home or in any directories wo. root rights: http://perlbrew.pl/

wget -O - http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash

```
perlbrew install perl-5.16.0
perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
```

you could call your perl from shell (scripts) like this: http://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-In-Shell-Scripts.html

If your servers are identical enough then you could rsync/rdist this directory to every host and you are done.