# An elegant way of returning the index of the last non-zero element in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I find myself wanting to find the index of the last non-zero element in an array.  So, given:

```
my @array = (0,0,5,9,0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0);
my $indexLastNonZero = insertElegantMethodHere(@array);
# expect $indexLastNonZero to be equal to 9;
```

I've done this:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
    $indexLastNonZero = $i if $array[$i] != 0;
};
```

I works but somehow I can't help feel there must be a super elegant (smarter? nice? more efficient?) way of doing this in perl.  I've looked into List::Utils but not found a nice way there and would like a non-core-module independent method.

Any thoughts?

Cheers

Comment: I think you mean 9, not 10.

Comment: Indeed, and I even counted the elements with my podgy finger to make sure I wouldn't make such a schoolboy error... and I still did it!  Must have **really** podgy fingers!

Comment: Question edited to have correct index as per @FMc's comment

Comment: "a non-core-module independent method" - this restriction would be far easier to take into account if you told us which version of Perl you're using.

Comment: Ok, I'll simplify -- no module!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start at the end of the array and work backwards until you find a non-zero element:

```
my @array = (0,0,5,9,0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0);

my $i = $#array;
$i-- while $i >= 0 && $array[$i] == 0;

print "The last non-zero element is at index $i\n";
```

The `$i >= 0` test is to guard against the edge case where all elements are zero. In that case the resulting value of `$i` is -1.

Comment: my second favourite of the solutions posted. thanks.  as many of you have enlightened me, the trick is to start looking from the end of the array!

Answer (score 13):

Use [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) for such tasks:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::MoreUtils;

my @array = (0,0,5,9,0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0);

print List::MoreUtils::lastidx { $_ } @array
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did look into List::MoreUtils but (and do correct me if I'm wrong) but I think it is not a core module and my questions specified that "would like a non-core-module independent method" (because the box I run on perl is not mine and I for various reasons, I can't add modules!).

Comment: @moigescr Then download the `List::MoreUtils` source and include it with your script.

Comment: @moigescr, That makes no sense. If you can install Perl from SO, you can install code from CPAN.

Comment: @ikegami, I can't install Perl (I use a linux box running Perl on which I am granted an account with limited privileges)... but I think we might be straying off-topic!

Comment: @moigescr ikegami's point was that if you can use Perl *code* from Stack Overflow, you can use Perl code from CPAN. Installing CPAN modules [does not require root access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735836/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-without-root-privileges); worst case, simply download the source and include it in your project (most CPAN modules are licensed under the GPL or the Artistic License). You're significantly limiting yourself by avoiding CPAN. Why re-invent wheels when others have already created, refined, and road-tested thousands of them for you?

Answer (score 5):

```
my @array = (0,0,5,9,0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0);
my ($indexLastNonZero) = grep $array[$_], reverse 0 .. $#array;
```

Comment: my personal favourite of solutions posted so far.  It feels nicely "perlish".  On the downside, if the array was huge (which in my case it is not) and mostly non-zero, that you'd be creating a large temporary array which @MichaelCarman's method does not.

Comment: This does a lot of extra work: It builds a list of indexes of the same size as the array, reverses it (creating a second list), and then finds the index of all non-zero elements (discarding all but the first).

Comment: @MichealCarman.  Indeed, it's far from efficient.. but I think it does look good and my array is small.  It's my favourite but I agree it's probably not the best (which at present is still yours ;))  Waiting to see if more ideas come through but close to giving you the nod ;)

Comment: @moigescr your approach is already efficient (`for (0..$#arr)` doesn't generate list internally) and you can shorten it if you like `$array[$_] and $indexLastNonZero = $_ for 0 .. $#array;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util), which is in core:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use List::Util qw(first);

my @array = (0,0,5,9,0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0);
my $index = @array;

first { $index-- && $_ } reverse @array;

print "Last index that is non-zero: $index\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructive approach so take a copy of the array first:

```
my @array2 = @array;
while (!pop @array2) {} # Remove up to and including the last non-zero
print scalar @array2;   # Size of remaining elements is index of last non-zero
```

Comment: fails to handle the case where all the elements are false

Answer (score 0):

```
sub last_true {
    pop and return scalar @_ while @_;
    undef;
}

my $index = last_true(@foo);
```