# problems when installing perl sftp module

Tags: linux, perl, sftp, redhat

I am using perl 5.8.8 on redhat 5.x. I went into direcotry perl/bin/ and execute **`cpan Net:SFTP`**,but encountered following issues. Could you help to check it?

```
………………………………………………………
…………………………………………

  CPAN.pm: Going to build T/TU/TURNSTEP/Math-GMP-2.07.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgmp
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Math::GMP
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

==========================================================

WARNING! No GMP libraries were detected!

Please see the INSTALL file.

===========================================================


Removing (Makefile)
Running make test
  Make had some problems, maybe interrupted? Won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, maybe interrupted? Won't install
Running make for T/TU/TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38.tar.gz
  Is already unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38

  CPAN.pm: Going to build T/TU/TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38.tar.gz

Couldn't chdir /root/.cpan/build/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38: No such file or directory at /usr/local/clo/xxx/xxxx/perl588/lib/5.8.8/CPAN.pm line 2137
```

Comment: Use Net::SFTP::Foreign instead.

Comment: thanks. it seems ok. And the installation time is very short compared to Net:SFTP. what does 'Foreign' here mean?

Comment: It means that it uses a foreign (non-perl, external) program to establish the SSH connection to the remote host, in contraposition to `Perl` as used in Net::SSH::Perl that is the base for Net::SFTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Red Hat Linux then use `up2date` command to install most common modules:

```
up2date module-name
```

For a basic understanding look at this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-install-a-perl-module/).

For more information look at this: [How to install perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3735836/4248931)

Comment: where is the command 'up2date '? Which path can i execute this command?