# Decode json in bugzilla template?

Tags: json, perl, bugzilla, template-toolkit

How to decode Json in Bugzilla template ?

how can I load the [JSON Plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/Template-Plugin-JSON-0.07/lib/Template/Plugin/JSON.pm) correctly?

```
    [% USE JSON ( pretty => 1 ) %];

    <script type="text/javascript">

            var foo = [% foo.json %];

    </script>

    or read in JSON

    [% USE JSON %]
    [% data = JSON.json_decode(json) %]
    [% data.thing %]
```

it's giving me an error that `plugin error - JSON: plugin not found`

Comment: version of Bugzilla is 5x

Comment: Do you have that plugin module installed?

Comment: I think yes , after doing ./checksetup.pl

I got a list of plugins, and the JSON XS is in 
                    
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.01)     ok: found v3.02

Comment: That sounds like you have the module _JSON_ (or _JSON::XS_) installed. That's not the same as your _Template::Plugin::JSON_. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736710/1331451 for how to install it. The easiest way will be `cpan Template::Plugin::JSON` or `cpanm Template::Plugin::JSON` on the command line of the host that's runing the Bugzilla installation.

Comment: Are they the same plugin JSON and JSON-XS, when I did [% USE JSON-XS %]  and error with  unexpected token (-) [% USE JSON-XS %]

Comment: You have to use `::` (two colons). The `-` minus is just used in distribution names. In code, you need the `::`. There is no JSON::XS plugin for Template Toolkit. In general, the _::XS_ says that it's not written in Perl, but rather it uses a C library that is connected to Perl to speed things up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114946/discussion-between-zico-and-simbabque).