# Format large integer in perl

Tags: perl

Is there a method in perl that takes a large number and formats it into postfix characters like 'M', 'K', etc.  For example:

```
number = 9,999,999    output = 10.0M
```

I can't use things like 'Math::Round' or 'Format::Number' as perl is installed and I cannot install any new modules.

Comment: *"I cannot install any new modules."* In case the issue is that you don't have root/admin privileges, [you don't need root to install modules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735836).

Comment: How precise does it have to be? How many numbers after the decimal have to be displayed?

Comment: Copy code from https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::FormatEng (pure Perl), just as you would copy code from any Answer here.

Comment: If you can use the code we post here, then you can install modules. If you can't use the code we post here, then what's the point of answering your question?

Comment: Sorry, the reason I can't install modules is because I'm running a script over ssh to about 500 servers.  I can't install it on each one.  So I needed some kind of routine like below which could do it.  I would like it to have 2 decimal places, so the answer like '9.54M' is perfect.

Comment: If you're running the script over SSH, that means you're copying the script to the remote hosts. So just copy any modules you need to the remote hosts, along with your script.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

```
$number=9876543;
$NumString = sprintf("%.1f M", int($number/100000 + 0.5)/10);
print "$number   $NumString\n";
```

OUTPUT:   `9876543   9.9 M`

Version with a subroutine

```
sub MegaNumber {
    my($number, $places) = @_;
    $d2 = 10**$places;
    $d1 = 1000000 / $d2;
    $fmt = "%.". $places . "f M";
    sprintf($fmt, int($number/$d1 + 0.5)/$d2);
}

print "9876543 ", MegaNumber(9876543, 1), "\n";
print "9876543 ", MegaNumber(9876543, 2), "\n";
print "987654 ",  MegaNumber(987654,  2), "\n";
```

Output:

```
9876543 9.9 M
9876543 9.88 M
987654 0.99 M
```