# Cumulative Density Function of a normal distribution calculation without installing a Math module

Tags: perl, module, cdf

I would like to calculate the Cumulative Density Function of a normal distribution in Perl. I am using the
[`Math::Gauss`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejanert/Math-Gauss-0.01/lib/Math/Gauss.pm)
module from CPAN which calculates a CDF without any problem.

#### ttt.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Gauss ':all';

my $x    = 0.1;
my $mean = 0;
my $std  = 0.1;

my $output = cdf($x, $mean, $std);

print $output;
```

However, I got a module installation problem when I ran the code in a different server as below:

> Can't locate Math/Gauss.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
> /etc/perl
> /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
> /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
> /usr/lib/perl5
> /usr/share/perl5
> /usr/lib/perl/5.14
> /usr/share/perl/5.14
> /usr/local/lib/site_perl
> . ) at ./ttt.pl line 5.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./ttt.pl line 5.

I don't have a root authority so I need to install it locally, but I think CDF calculation is not a big calculation. (The CDF equation is simple.)

So it would be great if I knew the way to calculate a CDF in Perl without any installation. Or is there a way to include `Math/Gauss.pm` in my code so I can use it without installation?

Comment: [You don't need root to install modules.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735836)

Comment: *"so I need to install it locally"* What happened with that option?

Comment: @Borodin - I installed it locally without any problem, but I wanted to run my code in other servers without any installation. so ikegami's way is good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a module based on [Math::Gauss](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Gauss).

```
# Copyright (C) 2011 by Philipp K. Janert
# No rights reserved by Eric L. Brine
#
# March 13th, 2017 - Eric Brine - Trimmed into light version of the module.
# 
# This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the same terms as Perl itself, either Perl version 5.10.1 or,
# at your option, any later version of Perl 5 you may have available.

package Math::GaussLite;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;
use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( cdf );

my $SQRT2PI = 2.506628274631;

sub pdf {
  my ( $x, $m, $s ) = ( 0, 0, 1 );
  $x = shift if @_;
  $m = shift if @_;
  $s = shift if @_;

  if( $s <= 0 ) {
    croak( "Can't evaluate Math::Gauss:pdf for \$s=$s not strictly positive" );
  }

  my $z = ($x-$m)/$s;

  return exp(-0.5*$z*$z)/($SQRT2PI*$s);
}

sub cdf {
  my ( $x, $m, $s ) = ( 0, 0, 1 );
  $x = shift if @_;
  $m = shift if @_;
  $s = shift if @_;

  # Abramowitz & Stegun, 26.2.17
  # absolute error less than 7.5e-8 for all x

  if( $s <= 0 ) {
    croak( "Can't evaluate Math::Gauss:cdf for \$s=$s not strictly positive" );
  }

  my $z = ($x-$m)/$s;

  my $t = 1.0/(1.0 + 0.2316419*abs($z));
  my $y = $t*(0.319381530
          + $t*(-0.356563782
            + $t*(1.781477937
              + $t*(-1.821255978
                + $t*1.330274429 ))));
  if( $z > 0 ) {
    return 1.0 - pdf( $z )*$y;
  } else {
    return pdf( $z )*$y;
  }
}

1;
```

(Honestly, since this is really just a formula, the Copyright doesn't provide much protection.)