# How to install CPAN modules in a server with no internet access and root privileges?

Tags: perl, cpan

Currently the system has perl 5.8.8 without a C-compiler, no internet access, and no root privileges. I would like to install this module locally in a specific directory so I can use it.

[Text::Iconv](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Iconv/Iconv.pm)

Comment: This package seems to use XS, i.e. it requires a C-compiler to install. If you use a linux distribution maybe binary packages are available for it. On Ubuntu for example you could just download the package http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libtext-iconv-perl and install it using dpkg -i. (Sorry, didn't see you need to install w/o root :(

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735836/1331451.